# Kinect User Silhouette Shader

Tags: shaders, glsl, kinect, cg

I have this usermap from kinect's depth data (size is 320x280) and i want to display it on my game. The problem, of course it's ugly (first image) and i want to have beautiful effect like in the second image

The usermap is put on a bilboard as a texture2D and i've been thinking i should use fragment shader. I'm wondering what kind of shader techniques i should use so i can possibly make the same effect as shown on second image

Usermap: http://www.azerdev.com/darkmachine/usermap.png

Glowing man: http://www.azerdev.com/darkmachine/silhouette.jpg

Comment: The links to the pictures don't work. I get a 404.